# Auto call and play an audio recorded message

Tags: android, phone-call, audio-playback-agent

I wish to make automated calls to a list of numbers to then play a recorded audio message to them. The ones that don't pick up get a call back later.

What's the cheapest and easiest way to develop this using some pre-existing tools? Any directions welcome.

Comment: Please note that in the US there's laws against doing this in many cases (for example if the number called is a cell phone).

Comment: Thanks for the note! Of course I would not want to brake the law - this is not in the states but in one of the emerging markets and the people subscribe to this service.

In some places, where the internet connectivity is not too good, it's the only way to get important news quickly. SMS gateway is the other, but is very expensive. And some people are illiterate.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using automated flow apps (`Automate` [link below] is one such app that I used. Disclaimer: I've no affiliation with app) to trigger automated calls. The flow was initiate on a GCM notification to the phone, which provided the number for call. With all permissions granted and conditions fulfilling (network, sim, call credits, etc.), app should be able to make call to the number.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to play an audio message for the receiver.
So, if you were looking for 'how' part, here's the how part. If you know the next steps, enlighten me!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en&gl=US